# Undefined reference when building AzerothCore module

Tags: c++, cmake, azerothcore

I followed the steps on how to install azerothcore. I remembered I could add Modules, so I went in the website of azerothcore and downloaded a few modules. Before I downloaded them I checked and saw it says that it's building on master core, but for some reason I have the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../../../modules/libmodules.a(ModulesLoader.cpp.o): in function `AddModulesScripts()':
/root/azerothcore/build/modules/gen_scriptloader/static/ModulesLoader.cpp:60: undefined reference to `Addmod_1v1_arena_masterScripts()'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/azerothcore/build/modules/gen_scriptloader/static/ModulesLoader.cpp:61: undefined reference to `Addmod_boss_announcer_masterScripts()'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/azerothcore/build/modules/gen_scriptloader/static/ModulesLoader.cpp:63: undefined reference to `Addmod_npc_buffer_masterScripts()'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/azerothcore/build/modules/gen_scriptloader/static/ModulesLoader.cpp:64: undefined reference to `Addmod_npc_spectator_masterScripts()'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/azerothcore/build/modules/gen_scriptloader/static/ModulesLoader.cpp:65: undefined reference to `Addmod_reward_shop_masterScripts()'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/azerothcore/build/modules/gen_scriptloader/static/ModulesLoader.cpp:66: undefined reference to `Addmod_solocraft_masterScripts()'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [src/server/apps/CMakeFiles/worldserver.dir/build.make:175: src/server/apps/worldserver] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1086: src/server/apps/CMakeFiles/worldserver.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

and I am not capable of fixing it. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `_master` from all module subdirectories.
You can avoid this error by using `git clone` or cloning the modules in general with a git interface, instead of downloading a .zip file.